# How do I change a Infragistics Ultragrid Column into a drop down list?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I have an UltraGrid populated with a SQL query. One of the columns, 'groupId' I would like to make a drop-down list. I have a SQL query for that as well. The Ultragrid is populated, but I can not figure the dropdownlist portion.

```
Private Sub LoadGrid()
    ' This is the table for the whole grid
    Dim sSql As String = "SELECT [categoryId], [groupId], [sortOrder], [active], [compositeGroup], [multipleValues] FROM [cp].[ec_category_metadatagroup]"
    Dim dt As DataTable = mobjGlobals.GetData(sSql, ConfigLookup.ApiKey).Tables(0)

    UltraGrid1.DataSource = dt

    ' This is the table for the groupId DropDownList Column
    sSql = "SELECT Id, Description FROM [cp].[ec_metadata_subgroup]"
    Dim ddt As DataTable = mobjGlobals.GetData(sSql, ConfigLookup.ApiKey).Tables(0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply settings the ValueList property for your column to an instance of a value list will create the DropDown for you. All you need is a function that transforms your DataTable in a ValueList or better an extension method for the DataTable object like this one

```
Module DataTableExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToValueList(dt As DataTable , valueMember As String, displayMember As String) As ValueList 
        Dim vl As ValueList = New ValueList()

        ' We follow the sort order set on the DataTable
        For Each r In dt.DefaultView
            vl.ValueListItems.Add(r(valueMember), r(displayMember))
        Next
        Return vl
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you can call this function in this way

```
' This is the table for the groupId DropDownList Column
sSql = "SELECT Id, Description FROM [cp].[ec_metadata_subgroup]"
Dim ddt As DataTable = mobjGlobals.GetData(sSql, ConfigLookup.ApiKey).Tables(0)
' Call the datatable's extension method 
Dim vl As ValueList = ddt.ToValueList("Id", "Description")

' And finally use the ValueList property from the column
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("groupid").ValueList = vl
```

Notice however that you should run this code inside the InitializeLayout event instead of doing inline after the initialization of the grid's DataSource.